# How do I calculate the up vector in a flight simulator?

Tags: opengl-es, 3d, opengl-es-2.0

I am writing 3D app for OpenGL ES 2.0 where the user sets a path and flies over some terrain. It's basically a flight simulator on rails.

The path is defined by a series of points created from a spline. Every timeslice I advance the current position using interpolation i.e. I interpolate between p0 to p1, then when I reach p1 I interpolate between p1 and p2, then finally back from pN to p0.

I create a view matrix with something analogous to gluLookAt. The eye coord is the current position, the look at is the next position along the path and an up (0, 0, 1). So the camera looks towards where it is flying to next and Z points towards the sky.

But now I want to "bank" as I turn. i.e. the up vector is not necessarily directly straight up but a changes based on the rate of turn. I know my current direction and my last direction so I could increment or decrement the bank by some amount. The dot product would tell me the angle of turn, and the a cross product would tell me if its to the left or right. I could maintain a bank angle and keep it within the range -/+70 degrees, incrementing or decrementing appropriately.

I assume this is the correct approach but I could spend a long time implementing it to find out it isn't.

Am I on the right track and are there samples which demonstrate what I'm attempting to do?

Comment: I might be wrong, but isn't a rotation matrix all you really need, assuming that the zero matrix means pointing up?

Answer (score 2):

Since you seem to have a nice smooth plane flying in normal conditions you don't need much... You are almost right in your approach and it will look totally natural. All you need is a cross product between 3 sequential points A, B, C: `cross = cross(A-B, C-B)`. Now cross is the vector you need to turn the plane around the "forward" vector: Naturally the plane's up vector is (-gravitation) usually (0,0,1) and forward vector in point B is C-B (if no interpolation is needed) now "side" vector is `side = normalized(cross(forward, up))` here is where you use the banking: `side = side + cross*planeCorrectionParameter` and then `up = cross(normalized(side), normalized(forward))`. "planeCorrectionParameter" is a parameter you should play with, in reality it would represent some combination of parameters such as dimensions of wings and hull, air density, gravity, speed, mass...

Note that some cross operations above might need swap in parameter order (cross(a,b) should be cross(b,a)) so play around a bit with that.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach sounds correct but it will look unnatural. Take for example a path that looks like a sin function: The plane might be "going" to the left when it's actually going to the right.

I can mention two solutions to your problem. First, you can take the derivative of the spline. I'm assuming your spline is a `f(t)` function that returns a point `(x, y, z)`. The derivative of a parametric curve is a vector that points to the rotation center: it'll point to the center of a circular path.

A couple of things to note with the above method: the derivative of a straight line is `0`, and the vector will also be `0`, so you have to fix the up vector manually. Also, you might want to fix this vector so it won't turn upside down.

That works and will look better than your method. But it will still look unnatural for some curves. The best method I can mention is quaternion interpolation, such as [Slerp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp).
At each point of the curve, you also have a "right" vector: the vector that points to the right of the plane. From the curve and this vector, you can calculate the up vector at this point. Then, you use quaternion interpolation to interpolate the up vectors along the curve.

Comment: The spline is a Catmull-rom spline. Essentially the user taps out some points that describe the basic path and then I add a closing point and tweak the control points and then I spit out a loop that represents the path. I use Catmull since the path goes straight through the points. By the time the flying happens the spline is gone and just the points remain. I have a slerp function but nothing to

Comment: ..  use it with. I was thinking that I could calculate interpolated points any arbitrary distance ahead so I could for example calculate the average direction for the next 5 timeslices and use it to compute the bank angle.

Comment: As I said, if you only use the points directly, the movement might look unnatural. Sudden direction changes won't always look nice.

Comment: When I say I use the points directly I'm talking about a hundred at least between each control point. So user taps in maybe 5 or 6 control points, the code creates a path containing 500 or 600 points that follow the spline. So the path is a fairly accurate approximation of the spline. The spline is described as variation of a value t from 0 to 1 so potentially I could incrementally navigate it directly by feeding it a value t. It might be slightly smoother but smoothness isn't an issue at present, just the banking.

Comment: I haven't said the curve is not smooth enough. If you use the curve **only** for calculating the up vector, the movement will be smooth but the **up vector** will sometimes look wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If position and rotation depends only on spline curvature the easiest way will be [Numerical differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation) of 3D spline (you will have 2  derivatives one for vertical and one for horizontal components).  Your UP and side will be normals to the tangent.